# Getting concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError when receiving message from the GCP pub/sub subscription

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

Trying to receive the messages from Pub/Sub SUbscription using StreamingPull but the callback function failed with timeout error  concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError .

Error:

```
streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 447, in result
raise TimeoutError()" 

def callback(message):
    message.ack()
    message_dict = {}
    my_message = message.data.decode('utf8')
    message_dict = eval(my_message)
    data = json.dumps(message_dict)
    data_json = json.loads(data)
    # iterating over the json object and capturing & updating the json file 
    for i in pipeLine:
        if i['moduleName'] == 'module1':
            i['processingHistory'][0]['firstArg'] ['subArg'] = data_json[0]
            i['processingHistory'][1]['firstArg'] ['anotherArg'] = data_json[1]
        
        
        
    subscriber_r = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber_r.subscription_path(project_id, cvd_subscription_id)
    streaming_pull_future = subscriber_r.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
    print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}..\n")
        
    # Wrap subscriber in a 'with' block to automatically call close() when done.
    with subscriber_r:
        try:
            streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
        except TimeoutError:
            streaming_pull_future.cancel()
            streaming_pull_future.result()
```

How to handle this error & fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably passing a value into timeout. When the timeout is set, it indicates how long you want the subscriber to receive messages. The call to `streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)` will error out after the timeout passes. If you want the subscriber to receive messages indefinitely, don't set the timeout in that statement (or set it to None).